# How to insert a record using Entity Framework with foreign key lookup in a single operation?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Let's say I want to insert a new car with its make:

```
public class Car {

 public int Id {get;set;}
 public string Name {get;set;}
 public MakeId {get;set;}

}

public class Make{

 public int Id {get;set;}
 public string Name {get;set;}     

}
```

Now let's say I have the Name of the make for the car I want to insert. I don't want to make a query for the make to retrieve the make id and later make a new query to insert the car. I want EF to produce something like :

```
INSERT INTO Cars (Name, MakeId)
 SELECT @name, m.Id FROM Makes m WHERE m.Name = @makeName
```

Is that possible somehow or just going down to ADO.NET ?

Comment: I think your SQL will also produce 2 queries.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. You can only create the relationship from `Car` to `Make` by either setting the foreign key property `Car.MakeId` to a valid key value of a `Make` or by setting a navigation property `Car.Make` to a `Make` entity that again has a valid key value. In both cases you need to know the primary key value `Id` of the `Make` you want to assign to the `Car`. Knowing any other property - like `Make.Name` - is not sufficient, even not if it is guaranteed to be unique by a unique key constraint in the database.